# Изображение во весь блок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать размер изображения во весь блок — 100% от размера блока (не от размера изображения)?

В Bootstrap есть класс `.img-responsive`, но там ширина изображения 100%. У меня его размер составляет 1024*768, следовательно на Large Display (больше 1200px) он будет меньше ширины блока.

Заранее спасибо!

**Пример кода**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="bg" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img id="bigImage" class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="graffittied building">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему Вы решили, что он будет меньше?

Comment: @humster_spb потому-что там max-width, а не width

Comment: В Bootstrap 3 при класе (.img-responsive) max-width: составляєт 100% от ширини изображения. А у мене ширина блока больше 1200 px, а максимальная ширина изображения 1024px. И следовательно оно меньше его ширини.... Как то так

Comment: Сделайте изображение фоном блока и растягивайте сколько хотите. Качество при этом будет ухудшаться, надо заметить

Comment: а зачем Вам вообще этот класс .img-responsive? если Вы зададите изображению width: 100%, оно и так у Вас будет резиновым

Answer (score -1):

У `.container` есть `padding` по умолчанию в `bootstrap`. Для `Large Display` в `media` напиши

```
.container {padding: 0;}
#bg img {width:100%; height:auto}
```

А вообще что бы картинки были responsive для любых размеров, можно добавить в

```
html width="1024", height="768" и в CSS 
#bg img {width:100%; height:auto}
```